How to create a single instance of a socket io that can be used across components and contexts in a react.js application?
I have a React.js application where I receive various types of data from a Python backend. The data I receive can be grouped logically into different groups. I want to have single instance of a socket io that receives all the data from the backend and then by listening to the different events I will handle each logical group of data in a different place in my application. This will make my code cleaner and easier to maintain. Sadly I have not been able to make it work.
So what I have done is to have a React context that handles the socket io instance. This context returns the socket io instance in various custom hooks I have made that are later called in components that need them. This part actually works except for one of my hooks that is being called not in a component but in another React context. Then I am unable to receive anything on this hook while on the other hooks data moves smoothly. An observation I had is that If I have 2 instances for the socket io communication, one of the hooks that are called in components and one for the hooks called in a React content, everything works fine but I do  want to have one instance only. Hopefully that was clear. Below you can see pieces of my code:
  // socket.js
import { io } from 'socket.io-client';

const socket = io('http://127.0.0.1:5000'); // Replace with your backend URL
socket.on('connect', () => console.info('socketIOContext Socket connected:',    socket.id));
socket.on('disconnect', () => console.info('socketIOContext Socket disconnected:', socket.id));
export default socket;


//SocketIOContext.js

// SocketContext.js
import React, { createContext } from 'react';
import socket from './socketIO';

export const SocketIOContext = createContext();

export const SocketIOProvider = ({ children }) => (
    <SocketIOContext.Provider value={socket}>
        {children}
    </SocketIOContext.Provider>
);

// hook whihI call the socket context

import { useEffect, useState, useContext } from 'react';
import SOCKET_TOPICS from '../sockets/socketIOTopics';

import { SocketIOContext } from '../contexts/socketIOContext';

export const useHookInAComponent = () => {
    const [dataX, setDataX] = useState(null);

    const socket = useContext(SocketIOContext);

    useEffect(() => {

        const handleEvent = (topic, callback) => {
            socket.on(topic, callback);
        };

        handleEvent(SOCKET_TOPICS.DATA_X, (data) => {
            setDataX(data)
        });

        return () => {
            Object.values(SOCKET_TOPICS).forEach((topic) =>   socket.off(topic));
     };
 }, []);

 return { dataX };
};


// hook which I call in a context

import { useEffect, useContext } from 'react';
// import io from 'socket.io-client';;
import SOCKET_TOPICS from '../sockets/socketIOTopics';
import { SocketIOContext } from '../contexts/socketIOContext';

const useHookThatICallInAContext = ({ 
 onDataY

}) => {
 const socket = useContext(SocketIOContext); // NOTE: This does not work; trying to have the same instance

 useEffect(() => {
     // const socket = io('http://127.0.0.1:5000'); // NOTE: This works, making 2 instances

     socket.on(SOCKET_TOPICS.DATA_Y, (data) => {
         if (onDataY) {
             onDataY(data)
         }
     });


     return () => {
         socket.off(SOCKET_TOPICS.DATA_Y);
     };
 }, []);
};

export default useHookThatICallInAContext;


I really have no clue what the issue might be. I wonder if it is possible that the issue has do with when the context is rendered, I am not sure. I hope I can get some help. Thank you,
